# How to traverse multiple different relationships from source node

Tags: groovy, gremlin

My graph looks like this

```
      P1
       |
      R1
       |
      Src
      /  \
     R2   R2
     /     \
    C1      C2
```

I'm trying to extract nodes Src, R2, C2, R1 and P1 where R represents relation and P,C is for parent and child nodes respectively.

I tried this:

```
g.V('src').out('R1', 'R2') // now i want some filters on node and relation depending upon type.
```

I was able to do it by visiting relation R1 from src and then coming back to Src and visiting the R2 and C2 but I'm trying to avoid the duplicate traversal.

I'm completely new in gremlin and have checked the documentation but couldn't find the specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of options, but I suppose the answer is dependent on what you ultimately want to accomplish. You could simply `project()` your result to a `Map` and handle each edge label independently if that fits your expected output:

```
g.V('src').
  project('r1','r2').
    by(out('R1').has(...)....fold())
    by(out('R2').has(...)....fold())
```

or if you aren't really ready for the "result" and don't need to segregate the two streams you could use `union()`:

```
g.V('src').union(out('R1').has(...), out('R2').has(...))....
```

Perhaps those options will provide some inspiration for you.

Comment: I'm new and want to go with union (looks simple), tx.